# Debug Android application on device without debugger

Tags: android, debugging

I am in a desperate situation.

I am developing an Android application using the ADT in Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.04 on a netbook.

Unfortunately the netbook is not powerful enough to run the Device Emulator (when I try there are always issues). Then, I tried to debug on-device, but unfortunately my phone (Pulse) seems to have some problem.

It seems I can't debug. I have already spent hours trying to get that working. And I can't afford to upgrade my netbook/mobile now.

The only thing I can do is developing on Eclipse and run the application on the phone.
Is there any way I can debug while the application is running on my phone? Can I create somewhere a log with errors/warnings and even some custom messages I put in the code?

What a situation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Are you at least able to run `adb shell` to access your phone shell? (btw I can confirm the emulator is practically unusable on a slow netbook)

Comment: Thanks Alexandre for confirming. Yes, I can run adb shell. Wow, I didn't know about that. I get a prompt with a dollar sign and I can launch ls, pwd, ... How can I use this to debug? Can I access any log with the command line? The problem is that I can't be root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On device debugging should work. Make sure you have `android:debuggable="true"` in your application manifest. I previously had debugging issues that fixed themselves after rebooting the device.

Alternately, you can use [the Log class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to print out log messages. These can be seen by running `adb logcat` or in the logcat view of Eclipse.

**Edit:**

It seems that on some devices you have to run `echo 1 > /sys/kernel/logger/log_main/enable` from `adb shell` to enable logging.

Comment: They are both 2 good suggestions but none of them did the trick

Comment: Now I am gonna try adb logcat

Comment: Unfortunately adb logcat doesn't seem to work for me; maybe I just used it the wrong way. In my program I added Log.v("MYAPP", "hello!"); Then I loaded the application on the phone and run it. From my Ubuntu I launched adb logcat but I didn't see anything, the prompt just blinks

Comment: Just to be sure are you launching `adb logcat` before that statement is reached in the code.

Comment: That was what I was doing (anyway good idea!). I have also tried Log.i("MYAPP", "hello2!");  but no luck

Comment: Maybe it is the way I create the apk. But I generate it by launching the Debug (that fails) on Eclipse. I would think that is the way

Comment: One more thing that may be important. To install the apk into the phone I run ./adb install /home/dan/workspace/Hello\ World/bin/Hello\ World.apk from my Ubuntu dev machine

Comment: I don't get it. There must be something wrong with your setup. If you can get to the phone shell you can also run the `logcat` command from there but I'm not sure it will make any difference.

Comment: Good idea. I have done that, but it leads to exactly the same result. There is a prompt that doesn't do anything when I run the program

Comment: Can I access directly the log file and tail it?

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to run 'less' or 'tail' I get:  permission denied

Comment: I have tried to run ./adb bugreport. The output contains a few section with a lot of data. When it reaches the ------ SYSTEM LOG ------ section, the prompt stucks and keeps on blinking...Probably some problem with the system log. I am going to try and google

Comment: "Maybe it is the way I create the apk. But I generate it by launching the Debug (that fails) on Eclipse. I would think that is the way" -- I always just use "run" (the green "play" button) and the debugger attaches automatically.

Comment: You should only click the green checkmark if this answer has solved your problem. It sounds like it hasn't.

Comment: Found the problem. From the mobile console, I needed to run: echo 1 > /sys/kernel/logger/log_main/enable to enable the logging

Comment: @dan You can post this as an answer and accept it yourself so as to make the solution more visible to other who share the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug an android application directly through a tool named DDMS included in the SDK. With Eclipse the plugin intgrates everything for you: just create a breakpoint on the line you want to stop to by double-clicking in the margin, then hit the 'debug' button (the little bug at the top of the window). The program will start on the device and the device will display a message 'waiting for debugger to attach'. The message should disappear within a few seconds and will stop at the line you put the breakpoint on.

As for create logs, you can use the android.util.Log class:

```
import android.util.Log;
...
Log.e("MYAPPLICATION", "my message");
```

This should show in the "Logcat" view of eclipse.

Comment: Does that work even if I can't do on-device debug and I can just run the apk on the device, as I said?

Comment: The Log class will work regardless of your setup; as long as you can install an application it will write to the log. There are applications that can show you the log on the device, but it is far more convenient to see it on your development machine with logcat. Now, if you can install an apk but not debug the application or logcat directly your device, you should look into how you installed the SDK because something is definitely wrong. It may also be the device - I know it is slow but just try it once with the emulator to see if adb logcat works. If it does, the problem is with your device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you wouldn't be able to debug on the device. Just make sure your device is recognized by Ubuntu by following this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).

Comment: I have tried that (and many other) but the Pulse seems to have some problems. I have read that on a forum. To workaround those issues I should recompile adb after changing the code but it doesn't sound easy